# Is there anyway to assign a default value of a table equal to the id itself?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-8

So I want to set the `default value` of the column `order` equal to the `id`. This is pretty much for sorting purposes.

Is there anyway to do it? Or would there be a better way to achieve the same purpose?

```php
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('title');
    $table->bigInteger('order');
    $table->string('path');
    $table->text('description')->default('');

    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: So sort on the `id` and you can remove the `order` column completely

Comment: but i want to make it possible to change the order, that's the reason I want a separate field

Comment: You can set the order field to be auto incrementing seperatly from the id. you dont need it to be the same as "id" you just need it to be in order.

Comment: @N69S I tried it, it gave me an error saying I can only have 1 auto incrementing field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in the following way. The created event will be called once it is created and will never call on updating

```
class Post extends Model
{
    protected static function booted() {
        self::created(function (self $post){
            $post->order = $post->id;
            $post->save();
        });
    }
}
```

[Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events-using-closures)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with laravel migrations, mysql doesn't support it on table creation.

You could create a mysql trigger to set the field on insert
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

The real question though is why do you want an identical field just for sorting reasons?

Comment: the reason is basically so I can change the order

Comment: @huhehu you can order by the "order" field and then by "id", in this way if you do not set a custom order they are sorted by id, for example:
`->orderBy('order', 'DESC')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')`

Answer (score 2):

Each time after you create/save a new entry in the posts table, just grab the id of the row and save it again:

```php
$post->save();
$post->order = $post->id;
$post->save();
```

It's not ideal as it requires an additional database operation for every post creation, but in reality it probably won't ever be an issue unless your project gets really big.

Comment: kind of want it automated though lol, cause practising laravel/vue

Comment: I understand the urge to solve it more cleanly but there may also be value in avoiding getting caught up on this small detail and being freed up to accomplish more on your actual project more quickly. Everything is a tradeoff, good luck

Comment: @huhehu always think this type of issues as: "if it is a business logic issue, a programming language like PHP or JS, or the framework must solve it, but not the DB... DB enforces rules or data, but not logic", so you **MUST** use PHP to solve this...

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't make this automated.

Even in MySQL 8.0 with expression defaults. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html which says:

> An expression default value cannot depend on a column that has the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute.

You can't write a trigger to do it. You can change column values only in a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger. But the auto-increment value for your `id` column has not been generated at that time. The auto-increment value is only available in an `AFTER INSERT` trigger, but by that time, you can't modify columns of the row, because it has already been inserted.

The only way to do what you want is to INSERT the row, and then subsequently run another SQL UPDATE to copy the auto-increment value from your `id` column to your `order` column.